GraphServiceClient with DelegateAuthenticationProvider was not found and how to change my code
I want to create a service that consumes Microsoft Graph API with reading the Outlook Calendar with this code
//Authenticate application
public class AuthenticationHelper
{
    private static string _clientId = "xxx";
    private static string _tenantId = "xxx";
    private static string _clientSecret = "xxx";
    private static string[] _scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(_clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{_tenantId}"))
            .Build();

        AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
}

//Call Microsoft Graph API
public class CalendarHelper
{
    private static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient(string accessToken)
    {
        return new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }));
    }

//Putting It All Together
public static async Task ListCalendarEventsAsync()
{
   string accessToken = await AuthenticationHelper.GetAccessTokenAsync();
   var graphClient = GetGraphClient(accessToken);

   var events = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.GetAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(events);
    }
}

At the CalendarHelper class, the GraphServiceClient is unable to find the DelegateAuthenticationProvider of the GraphServiceClient method.
Does anyone can solve my code this pattern?

Check the doc for SDK v5, DelegateAuthenticationProvider cannot be used in v5. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#authentication

You are using client credentials flow to generate the access token which won't work with calling /me endpoint. Switch to delegated flows like interactive flow or authorization code flow to fetch signed-in user calendar.

Note that, you are using client credentials flow to generate the access token which won't work with calling /me endpoint. Alternatively, switch to delegated flows like interactive flow or authorization code flow.
I registered one Entra ID application and granted Calendars.Read permission of Delegated type as below:

For interactive flow, make sure to add redirect URI in Mobile and Desktop applications platform and enable public client flow option like this:

In my case, I ran below sample code that uses interactive flow and got signed-in user's calendar events successfully like this:
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read" };

        var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
            ClientId = clientId,
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"), 
        };

        var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

        await ListCalendarEventsAsync(graphClient);
    }

    private static async Task ListCalendarEventsAsync(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        try
        {
            var events = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Events.GetAsync();

            foreach (var calendarEvent in events.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Event:");
                Console.WriteLine($"Subject: {calendarEvent.Subject}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Start: {calendarEvent.Start?.DateTime}");
                Console.WriteLine($"End: {calendarEvent.End?.DateTime}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Location: {calendarEvent.Location?.DisplayName}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Organizer: {calendarEvent.Organizer?.EmailAddress?.Address}");

                Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Response:

Reference:
List events - Microsoft Graph v1.0

try to implement from your guid with and I got this error
{"InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details. Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
And I can't understand what happend and to do next :(

Could you confirm whether you added redirect URI in Mobile and desktop platform or not? Have you enabled public client flow option? Please edit your question and add Authentication tab image of your application from Portal
